# List field with only one element casting problem

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in postgresql table that is a **list** with only one element and this element is always an integer or null.

I am trying to use this field in a query like this:

```
select
sum(case when value = 1  then 1 else 0 end) as count_of1
sum(case when value = 2  then 1 else 0 end) as count_of2
from tbl
```

and returns:  `operator does not exist: text=integer` but as mentioned above I cant't cast it to numeric for some unknown reasos.

I am trying to cast this field and I always get an error.  Tried:

```
value::numeric,  
value::float, 
value::integer
```

and I always get an error of casting.

```
pg_typeof(value) ->>  'text'
```

Comment: What's the error you get when you cast the value?

Comment: "*is always an integer or null*" obviously not if you can't cast it to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is defined as `text`, then compare it to a text value:

```
sum(case when value = '1' then 1 else 0 end)
```

alternatively:

```
count(*) filter (where value = '1')
```

---

But `value::integer` should work if **all** values in that column can be cast to an integer if there is at least one row with a value that can't be converted, this will fail.